# what is interfering with the new environment here?

Tags: environments

Basically I wanted to modify the `description` list so that the first word(s) are underlined and bold

If you compile this file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\newenvironment{mydescription}{%
   \renewcommand\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace{\labelsep}\textbf{\ul{##1}}}
   \begin{description}%
}{%
   \end{description}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mydescription}
  \item[First] Test
  \item[Second] Test
\end{mydescription}


\end{document}
```

---

The output is okay. But if you compile the following, you see that the environment is not what it is supposed to be. What commands in the preamble are interfering with the compilation and how to solve this issue?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Lecture 1}
\rhead{Handout 2}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc,graphs,decorations.markings}
\def\annotateEquality#1{ %for the arrow from equality sign
\tikz[overlay]
  \draw[blue,<-] (-1.5ex,1.5ex) -- +(.7,.5) node[right] {#1};
}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\verteq}{\rotatebox{90}{$\,\neq$}}
\newcommand{\equalto}[2]{\underset{\scriptstyle\overset{\mkern4mu\verteq}{#2}}{#1}}


\usepackage{enumitem,array}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} %for proof 
\newtheorem*{mythm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{mydef}{Definition}
\usepackage{centernot} %for `not implies' symbol

\usepackage{amssymb} %for 'therefore' symbol
\usepackage{tikz-cd}% Commutative diagram 
\title{\ul{Expectations in Bivariate Probability Distribution}}
\date{}

\everymath=\expandafter{\the\everymath\displaystyle}

\tikzset{degil/.style={
                decoration={markings,
                mark= at position 0.5 with {
                \node[transform shape] (tempnode) {$\backslash$};
                %\draw[thick] (tempnode.north east) -- (tempnode.south west);
                }
                },
                postaction={decorate}
}
}

\newenvironment{mydescription}{%
   \renewcommand\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace{\labelsep}\textbf{\ul{##1}}}
   \begin{description}%
}{%
   \end{description}%
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
%These define a new itemize environment with 'invisible' bullets
\newenvironment{Myitemize}{%
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{{}}%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]}{\end{itemize}}
\maketitle 
\thispagestyle{fancy}

 \begin{mydescription}
 \begin{mydescription}
 \item[First] Test
 \item[Second] Test
 \end{mydescription}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what you're doing here, but you might try replacing `\begin{description} ... \end{description}` _inside_ your `\newenvironment` by `\description ... \enddescription`, which removes one extra layer of grouping.

Comment: I'm also not sure what you are trying to do but it looks like you are just trying to modify the behaviour of the enumerate and description environments. If this is all that you want then the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package gives a very neat way of doing this.

Comment: we don't see that it is not what it is supposed to be unless you tell us what it is supposed to do.

Comment: you are missing `%` from ends of lines (which may not be related) `\ul{##1}}}%`, `#1{%for the arrow`

Comment: @tohecz: I'm afraid removing curly brackets didn't work out

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a look at it. But I think the problem here is a bit different

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have modified the question, thanks very much. I'm afraid I did not get your point on the %. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: your definition of `mydescription` is missing a `%` at the end of the second line and your definition of `\annotateEquality` has a misplaced comment there should be no space before `%for the arrow ` see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'm afraid the solutions as far as `%` is concerned didn't work. In fact there are errors when I try to provide an option in [...] to the \item in the list... Would you like me to enter chat?

Comment: Sorry, but "didn't work" is not quite descriptive.

Comment: It's a conflict between `enumitem` and `soul`. Why do you want to underline the label in the first place? Underlining is considered a bad typographical device.

Comment: Ciao @egreg (Enrico): Thanks for pointing it out. I didn't not about it, but it was already there in someoneelse's notes. So I was just reproducing the format in my document :-)

Comment: @tohecz: Thanks very much. Basically I meant the (same) situation regarding the errors remains (if you compile the 2nd example above)

Answer (score 5):

It happens that `soul` commands cannot be used in the optional argument to `\item`, when `enumitem` is loaded: they're quite fragile and don't like to appear in particular places (you get `Reconstruction failed` besides the `\enit@align` error).

You could use `ulem`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{mydescription}{%
   \renewcommand\descriptionlabel[1]{%
     \hspace{\labelsep}\textbf{\uline{##1}}%
   }%
   \begin{description}%
}{%
   \end{description}%
}

\begin{document}

 \begin{mydescription}
 \item[First] Test
 \item[Second] Test
 \end{mydescription}

\end{document}
```

but the best thing is forgetting about underlining, which is considered bad practice in fine typography.

[image]