# how to underline the enumerate number automatically

Tags: enumerate

```
\begin{enumerate}[\textit{Step} \itshape 1 :]
```

I want italic and underline "Step 1".
What should I add to underline "Step 1"?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please add a complete, small working example (Minimum Working Example) of code which illustrates your question. Why do you use both `\textit` and `\itshape`?

Comment: Use italic and underline is redundant typographically. You must decide to use only one method or italic or underline. Italic is the method used in the printers tradition, whereas that underline comes from the 19th century and the days where the typewriter was the cutting edge technology, but typographical more limited.

Comment: Wow, I just had a very similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196977/what-is-interfering-with-the-new-environment-here. Apparently the `soul` package and `enumitem` interfere with each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that, if you insist, with the `enumitem` and `ulem` packages:

```
        \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}
        \usepackage{ulem} 
        \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{enumerate}[label = \uline{\textit{Step \arabic*:}}]
            \item First item.
            \item Second item
            \item A third item
         \end{enumerate}

        \end{document}
```

[image]